# Audit trail for Rails app

Tags: audit

I am looking to add an audit trail to our Rails app. At the moment, I am trying to lock down my requirements and determine the appropriate software architecture.

Our website gets about one hundred million page requests a week, and growing. We currently log a subset of actions into a MySQL table, but that table is much too large and drags down performance of the rest of the app. It's therefore hard to imagine solutions such as [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) or [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) would work out. We also can't just keep around our log files, even compressed, because they are huge.

So, what sort of software architecture is appropriate here?

Comment: paper_trail allows you to specify which table audit records are persisted to. As such, you could do a table per object, which might help with performance by reducing the number of records per table. I'm not sure if you missed that or if such a suggestion is even appropriate in regards to your data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Separate tables for separate models is helpful, and perhaps we could store the data in an entirely separate SQL server (possibly via a small pull request to paper_trail). That'd help a bit, but not enough for our particular use case.

Comment: Hi @ChrisInEdmonton, I am currently solving a similar challenge. Might I as you how did you figure it out? Thanks.

Comment: We never did. We currently store our data in MySQL, but with row counts approaching the billions, we are planning on taking a look into various NoSQL stores.